# TypeError: int() argument must be a string, a bytes-like object or a number, not 'list' (Python3.6)

Tags: python-3.x, sum, typeerror

For this code, I'm trying to list out all the numbers from the lines that begin with New Revision. I managed to do that as shown below under the **"Filtered x values"**. However, I'm stuck at the point where I need to sum all of the "Filtered x values" as it keeps prompting with Type error even though I change the x data type from string to integer. What might be wrong here?

```
import re
hand = open('D:/Python/mbox-short.txt')
count = []
y = list()
k = 0
a = 0
for line in hand:
    line = line.rstrip()
     x = re.findall('^New Revision: ([0-9.]+)', line)
     if len(x) > 0:
         k = (x)
         a = a + int(k)
         print(k)  //This is a list of filtered values (x)
 print(a)
```

**Filtered x values**

```
['39772']
['39771']
['39770']
['39769']
['39766']
['39765']
['39764']
['39763']
['39762']
['39761']
['39760']
['39759']
['39758']
['39757']
['39756']
['39755']
['39754']
['39753']
['39752']
['39751']
['39750']
['39749']
['39746']
['39745']
['39744']
['39743']
['39742']


TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-247-8432b00ac729> in <module>()
 10     if len(x) > 0:
 11         k = (x)
 ---> 12         a = a + int(k)
 13         print(k)
 14 print(a)

 TypeError: int() argument must be a string, a bytes-like object or a number, 
 not 'list'
```

Comment: `findall` returns a list, `k` is a list containing a string, you probably want `re.search` and then `.group()` on the return value of that

Comment: Does replacing `a = a + int(k)` with `a = a + int(k[0])` fixes it?

Comment: Thanks for your feedbacks. Yes , this line (a = a + int(k[0])) works as well.